# Why does Docker Stack Deploy have Swarm Manager Error only with remote Jenkins deploy?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-swarm

So I have a basic image and it's been tested locally and via SSH, it works fine. But when I try to deploy it via Jenkins sh, that's where issues appear.

When I remote into the Instance and run the following:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file=simpleTest.yml simpleTestService
```

My service works fine. However, when the same command is ran by my Jenkins Agent - I get

> node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm
> join" to connect this node to swarm and try again

I'm not sure why this is happening? Is it because I need to tell the Jenkins Agent to join the Swarm Manager (how?)

Here is my sample .yml. As far as I know, the docker-compose version is dictated by the "3" I have in the YML and my Docker version is 19.03.13-CE. My Jenkins Agent is on a different instance and I pull the image from a repository and push it to the target instance (where Docker sits). Info shows the Swarm is active and it's the manager. When I ran it on the actual instance, I edited the image name to have the name and tag of a build that exists in my repo (I used the same image and tag that Jenkins used as well to rule any weird inconsistencies out).

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: "${FULLNAMEWITHTAG}"
    container_name: SimpleTest
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing the SSH plugin and making Jenkins SSH in to do the command. That way, it actually deployed the stack as the Swarm Manager.

Unless explicitly told to do so, running a SH script with Docker Swarm will not automatically join a Swarm or perform the action as a worker node. So you do need to either join the Swarm or SSH into the box (and thus act as Manager)

Answer (score 1):

The node you want to deploy the stack to has to be in a swarm in order to do so. Not sure how you configured Jenkins, but to be safe you may just init the swarm (maybe it's working on the node you are running the command on, but Jenkins uses another agent... Double check that!).

The error message is already kind of telling you the solution, just make Jenkins run the `docker swarm init` command. How you accomplish depends. Below is an example for declarative pipelines:

```
steps {
   [...]
   sh 'docker swarm init'
   [deploy the stack]
}
```